# Overflow text on both left and right

Tags: css

How do I center text with css so it overflows both left and right? I see questions here that make text overflow left *instead* of right, but I want it to look like the text is zoomed in.

```
<body>
    <div class="page">
        SOMEHEADER
    </div>
</body>
```

-

```
.page {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:70%;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-size:8em;
    word-wrap:none;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mehulkar/QZCuY/) with a demo of what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 16):

Not the most elegant solution, but it seems to work.

HTML:

```
<div class="page">
    <div>
        SOMEHEADER
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.page > div {
    margin: 0 -1000%;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/grc4/w36mX/

This method works by stretching the inner div such that it is wide enough to fit its content completely (without wrapping/overflowing). The content is then centred (`text-align: center`) and clipped to size by the outer div (`overflow: hidden`).

The tricky part is to make the inner div wide enough to fit the text. Whenever it isn't wide enough, the text will overflow to the right so that it's not properly centred (as seen in your original jsFiddle).

By using [negative margins](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/), you can stretch the element by a certain amount to both the left and the right. If you know that the size of the text is 400px for example, then you could use `margin: 0 -200px` to ensure that the inner div is always at least 400px wide (200px to the left and 200px to the right). When you don't know the exact size of the text, you could either use percentages or a really high px value.

`margin: 0 -100%` would stretch the div by 100% of its original size to the left and 100% again to the right, making it 3 times larger than the `.page` div is. The text is about 900px wide, so this method would stop working if the `.page` div got below 300px wide (try resizing your browser in jsFiddle with `margin: 0 -100%` to see what I mean).

`margin: 0 -1000%` stretches the div to make it 21 times larger, which is usually enough to fit the text.

Comment: This works great. Can you explain why it's working though? `-1000%` of what? Also, `-100%` seems to work the same?

Comment: I've added an explanation.

Comment: This worked well for centering the <span> text inside of my <button>. I just applied `margin: 0 -1000%;` to the span and boom, it was centered!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work if the containing box is too small. I wanted to have it overflow and center on a div that's 0px wide, to be able to absolute position the element correctly, for that I used transform: translate(-50%, 0); on the inner div instead, see fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/1z4r3ywf/5/

Answer (score 1):

See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QZCuY/3/ I've tested it in latest Chrome, FF and IE7-9

HTML(`<div class="text">` added):

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="text">
        SOMEHEADER
    </div>
</div>
<p> 
    How do I get the header to overflow left <u>and</u> right instead of just to the right?
</p>
```

​CSS (`.page` has two new properties and new .text class):

```
body {
    background-color:green;
}
.page {
    position:relative;
    height:1em;

    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:red;
    width:70%;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-size:8em;
    word-wrap:none;
}
p {
    width:70%;
    margin:50px auto 0;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:2em;
}

.text {
    position:absolute;
    right:-50%;
    left:-50%;
}
​
```

Comment: `word-wrap: none;` is not a valid value, and leaving this parameter away consequently will not change the result. other than that, the solution worked for me in quite a different context (and leaving out quite some more), thanks. the essential seems to me the `position: absolute;` in the `.text` style (obviously mandating a `position: relative;` somewhere upstream in then DOM tree).